# Easiest way to create an auto increment field in Firebird database

Tags: field, firebird, auto-increment

Is there an easy way to create auto increment field using Firebird? I have installed the FlameRobin admin tool, but the process of creating an auto increment field through the tool is complex. Can I not create such an identity field just by clicking a checkbox or using some other tool other than Flamerobin?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

## Firebird 3 and later

In Firebird 3 it is easy to create, as it introduced identity columns. In practice it is syntactic sugar for generating a sequence + trigger (as shown for Firebird 2.5) for you.

For example

```sql
create table t1 (
   id integer generated by default as identity primary key
)
```

Firebird 3 only supports "`generated by default`", which means users are able to specify their own id values (which might lead to duplicate value errors); "`generated always`" has been [added in Firebird 4](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/4_0/rlsnotes40.html#rnfb40-ddl-identity).

See also the [Firebird 3 release notes, section "*Identity Column Type*"](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity), and the [Firebird 4.0 Language Reference, section "*Identity Columns (Autoincrement)*"](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/chunk/en/refdocs/fblangref40/fblangref40-ddl-table.html#fblangref40-ddl-tbl-identity).

## Firebird 2.5 and earlier

Firebird 2.5 and earlier do not have auto-increment fields. You need to create them yourself with a sequence (aka generator) and a trigger.

Sequence is the SQL standard term and generator is the historical Firebird term; both terms are available in the Firebird DDL syntax.

To [create a sequence](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-ddl-sequence):

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE t1_id_sequence;
```

To create a trigger to always generate the id on a table `T1` with primary key `ID`:

```sql
set term !! ;
CREATE TRIGGER T1_AUTOINCREMENT FOR T1
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  NEW.ID = next value for t1_id_sequence;
END!!
set term ; !!
```

See also: [How to create an autoincrement column?](http://firebirdfaq.org/faq29/)

### Using FlameRobin

FlameRobin also provides tooling to create a sequence + trigger for you. If you have an existing table, you can follow these steps:

1. Open the table properties:

   [image: open table properties]
2. Open the column properties of the primary key column

   [image: open column properties]
3. Default column properties, select *new generator* and *create trigger*:

   [image: default column properties]
4. Generator (sequence) and trigger code generated by FlameRobin. Note that contrary to my example above this trigger allows a user to specify their own id value, with some logic to avoid future duplicates. Execute this (and don't forget to commit):

   [image: generated code for generator + trigger]

Comment: `Firebird 3 only supports "generated by default", which means users are able to specify their own id values (which might lead to duplicate value errors)` Maybe it's because I'm not a DBA, but this is only for `INSERT` statements right? This doesn't have a problem for `UPDATE` right?

Comment: @searchengine27 I'm not sure what you're asking. Values are only generated on insert.