# How to populate column using generator?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, firebird

I'm creating an ASP.NET MVC web application in C#. I have a model class created which is based on a Firebird database. The trouble I am having is when I insert a new record into a table, the generator for the table is not being called - so I end up with a `NULL` value in that column.

How can I specify on a per-table/per-field basis which columns are `IDENTITY` columns and link them to their respective GENERATORS in Firebird?

Comment: What is the DDL of the table and its trigger? Also, consider using Firebird 3 which supports identity columns. It sounds like you haven't defined a trigger to use the generator. This doesn't happen automatically (it does happen automatically when using Firebird `generated by default as identity).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - what do you mean by using Firebird `generated by default as identity?  How do I do that in Firebird 2.5?

Comment: You can't with Firebird 2.5. That comment should have been _"when using Firebird 3's `generated by default as identity`"_, I must have been distracted while typing that. Otherwise see the answer by Mr. Nice (or my answer he linked) on how to create a trigger.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - Sounds good, thank you for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Create Generator**

```
CREATE SEQUENCE GEN_TESTTABLE_ID
```

**2. Create Trigger**

```
CREATE TRIGGER testtable_bi FOR testtable
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
AS
BEGIN
  IF (NEW.id IS NULL) THEN
    NEW.id = GEN_ID(gen_testtable_id,1);
END
```

**3. Create procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_gen_testtable_id
RETURNS (id INTEGER)
AS
BEGIN
  id = GEN_ID(gen_testtable_id, 1);
  SUSPEND;
END
```

In Firebird 3 you could use identity primary key

```
create table t1 (
   id integer generated by default as identity primary key
)
```

[Also a useful answer link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34555507/5789624)