# inserting a row having no values for Primary Key columns fails

Tags: stored-procedures, firebird, sql-insert, firebird2.5

For the following table:
[image]

I run the following stored procedure:

[image]

I'm redirected to "Results" tab and seeing nothing. Then if I click on "refresh" icon (below Results tab), then I get the dialog saying:

SQLCODE = -625 validation error for column ID, value "*** null ***"

[image]

And of course, nothing is added...

As far as I understand, firebird expects somevalue for RC_ID (which is my PK and should principally automatically incremented). If I give value also for RC_ID, it is working well.

So, what should I do to make a clear "insert" without these errors?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not setting a value for the primary key. Contrary to your expectation, primary keys are not automatically incremented. This is the case in any database I'm aware of. You always need to mark it as an identity, auto increment or generated, or something else to get that behavior, although some tools (table builders) may already apply this for you by default.

If you are using Firebird 3, you can define your column as `GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY` (see [Identity Column Type](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-ddl-enhance.html#rnfb30-ddl-identity) in the Firebird 3 release notes). For earlier Firebird versions the best way is to define a sequence (also known as generator) with a before insert trigger that populates the primary key column.

For more details on how to define an identity column (or define the trigger), see my answer on this question: [Easiest way to create an auto increment field in Firebird database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34553826/easiest-way-to-create-an-auto-increment-field-in-firebird-database).

Comment: `This is the case in any database I'm aware of.` - find the text "MySQL gotchas", notice that the text specifically targets MySQL v.3 as later MySQL versions like MySQL 5 became much more like database servers. However the text mentioned still might be worth reading as a thriller and nightmare fuel. Okay, here it seems to be, stay scared. http://sql-info.de/mysql/gotchas.html

Comment: @Arioch'The I have never used MySQL 4 or earlier, and I don't really care about the minutiae of ancient versions. And in MySQL 5.x and higher you need to explicitly define it as `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 0):

In firebird, the autoincrement was not working like in MySQL. Thus, sending a value for RC_ID was a must...

I found some working examples based on idea:

- create a generator
- assign it to column (PK)
- call GEN_ID with that generator like this:

:

```
   begin
      insert into RESERVATIONCATEGORY (RC_ID, RC_NAAM)
      values (
      GEN_ID(GEN_RESERVATIONCATEGORY _ID,1), 'selam'
      );
      suspend;
    end
```

Comment: there is no explicit auto-increment in Firebird 2, so it is not "working differently" it just does not exits. There is autoincrement in Firebird 3 and it works more or less how other auto-increment types in SQL servers which have them.